# Mail() not works with 2 variable or more

Tags: php, html, email

I would like to Understanding why this script does not work.

```
$to = $email_utente;

$subject = "Crono - nuovo task inserito";

$headers = 'From: CRONO <email@email.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

$message  = "Ciao <b>".$login_session."</b>,";
$message .= "hai inserito un nuovo task su Crono!";

$message .= "Ecco il riepilogo dei tuoi dati:";
$message .= "Task: ".$nome_task."";
$message .= "Cliente: ".$cliente."";
$message .= "Tipo: ".$tipo."";
$message .= "Data inserimento: ".$data_inizio_new.";
$message .= "Data fine(Prevista): ".$data_fine_new.";
$message .= "Note: ".$note."";


$message .= "Grazie per aver utilizzato Crono.";


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

if I comment all the different variables except one, the mail arrives properly. If, however, I remove the comment from the code, the email does not arrive.

Why is this happening?

thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting. See an issue?

Comment: You have problem with `"` in code.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: syntex error on that line  $message .= "Data inserimento: ".$data_inizio_new.";

Comment: Are you sure that all of the variables are set? Do any notices appear?

Comment: I'd just use a heredoc for this, or in one piece with one variable. You're overcomplicating things here and error reporting would have told you about the errors you made. *sera molto facile!*

Comment: I use with HTML like this
$message .= "<p style='font-size:16px; margin:0px;'>Task: ".$nome_task."</p>";

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$message .= "Data inserimento: ".$data_inizio_new.";
$message .= "Data fine(Prevista): ".$data_fine_new.";
```

to

```
$message .= "Data inserimento: ".$data_inizio_new;
$message .= "Data fine(Prevista): ".$data_fine_new;
```

or

```
$message .= "Data inserimento: ".$data_inizio_new."";
$message .= "Data fine(Prevista): ".$data_fine_new."";
```

every double quote(or single quote) should be matched with another double quote(or single quote).

Comment: ok, the code works, but i must implement HTML code inside the string.

<p style='font-size:16px; margin:0px;'>Task: <b>".$nome_task."</b></p>";

Comment: @Reverter, updated my ans

Comment: sorry man.-...look this code

$message .= "<p style='font-size:16px; margin:0px;'>Ecco il riepilogo dei tuoi dati:</p><br>";
$message .= "<p style='font-size:16px; margin:0px;'>Task: <b>".$nome_task."</b></p>";
$message .= "<p style='font-size:16px; margin:0px;'>Cliente: <b>".$cliente."</b></p>";
$message .= "<p style='font-size:16px; margin:0px;'>Tipo: <b>".$tipo;
$message .= "<p style='font-size:16px; margin:0px;'>Data inserimento: <b>".$data_inizio_new."</b></p>";

not works

Comment: so use heredocs

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing some double quotes at the ends of these lines:

```
$message .= "Data inserimento: ".$data_inizio_new.";
$message .= "Data fine(Prevista): ".$data_fine_new.";
```

Comment: one extra quote here, why not `$message .= "Data inserimento: ".$data_inizio_new;`

Comment: Or even `$message .= "Data inserimento: $data_inizio_new";`